# Graphing inequalities, elementary geometry (Highschool level)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, functions, graphing-functions

I am going through some past papers, and one of the few questions I need help with are:

[image]

[image]

For the second one, relating to plotting $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$, I made a table of values starting from $0$ until I got math error, and then from behind $0$ until I got maths error, then graphed it. I'm not sure if that is the right way since it took a really long time.

$y \leq 2$ part is easy,

For the first question I found that b is alternate of $\angle ADB$, which has to be $180^\circ - 63^\circ - 47^\circ = 70^\circ$. I also figured that $\angle ADC$ has to be $180^\circ - 47^\circ - 34^\circ = 99^\circ$, and since opposite sides are equal in a parallelogram, a has to be $99- 70=29$. Is this correct?

Comment: 47, 63, and 34 are the lengths of the sides, not the angles. In this question, you don't need to know the angles. You are on the right track using "opposite sides are equal in a parallelogram". What is the side opposite to $a$?

Comment: Your calculator method works, but can you figure out algebraically when exactly you will get a "math error"? Remember, negative numbers don't have (real) square roots.

Comment: @M.Vinay I don't know how to algebraically determine when a math error will occur, but I do know the answer is x cannot equal >= 5 just by looking at the expression

Comment: @Alatma, Notice that $y\geq \sqrt(4-x^2)$ is all the points on the boundary and vertically above the circle $x^2+y^2=2$ and $y \leq 2$ is all the points on and below the horizontal line $y=2$

Comment: For the square root to have a (real) value, $4 - x^2$ cannot be negative, so $4 - x^2 \ge 0$, or $4 \ge x^2$, which means the maximum possible value of $x$ is $4$.